# Using aggregate function max in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
select 
    sub.W
from 
    (select 
        W, count(W) as N
     from L
     group by W) sub
where 
     sub.N >= max(sub.N)
```

and I get this error:

> *Error code 1111, SQL state HY000: Invalid use of group function*
>   *Line 1, column 1*

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
select sub.W
from 
(
       select W, count(W) as N
       from L
       group by W
) sub
where n >= (select max(N)
            from
            (
              select count(W) as N
              from L
              group by W
            ) x)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab540/3)

Comment: works well. wow so compilcated for something basic. thanks!! what's the "x" about? is it mandatory?

Comment: the `x` is an alias for the subquery. If you remove it you will most likely get an error because an alias is required for derived tables

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select sub.W    
from 
(
       select W, count(W) as N
       from L
       group by W
) sub    
where sub.N >= (select max(N)
                from (
                       select W, count(W) as N
                       from L
                       group by W
                      ) sub2)
```